# My Hats Are Floating Away!

Tags: bug, status-declined, winterbash, user-profile

If you start with a full sized window and then shrink it, this is what happens...

[image: My hat has left my head.]

It also works in reverse.  I haven't tried any other browsers yet; this was achieved using Chrome.  Help!

Comment: Successfully reproduced on Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've actually known about this for a while, but there's not a good, easy fix for it. Just hit refresh and it should realign itself!

Comment: I figured this was because the hats were absolutely positioned from somewhere "far away" in the DOM but this isn't the case! Why not just make .gravatar position:relative and calc the left/top of .hat  from .gravatar rather than the window?

Comment: `[status-meh]`.